# Why the scrollview not position at the top?

Tags: swiftui

I have tried to use ZStack to place a background image and a scrollview inside

```
struct DetailView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            // ZStack: Background, ScrollView(vertical)
            ZStack {
                
                Image("background_brown").resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(geometry.size, contentMode: .fill)
                    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                    .frame(width:UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height:UIScreen.main.bounds.height)
                    .border(Color.yellow, width: borderWidth)
                
                ScrollView(.vertical/, showsIndicators: true, content: {
                    
                   Text("hello")
                }).frame(width:UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height:UIScreen.main.bounds.height)
                .border(Color.yellow, width: borderWidth)
                
               
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, I found that the scrollview bottom is out of the screen bound. why it is the case?

[image]

Comment: It’s already given answer in your last question

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are setting an item within the ZStack to have a frame of UIScreen.main.bounds.height. So the `ZStack`, which INCLUDES the safe areas, is starting within the top safe area and sizing its height to be `UIScreen.main.bounds.height`.

In you're code, you can probably just use `geometry.size.height` instead of `UIScreen.main.bounds.height` for the frame and it will work. However, you could instead use a `.background` modifier, like this:

```
struct DetailView2: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: true, content: {
            Text("hello")
        })
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
        .background(
            GeometryReader { geometry in
                Image("background_brown").resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                    .frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: geometry.size.height)
            }
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Something is wrong with GeometryReader. I'm not sure why you're using it for the background image. You can simply set background like this and then it will work fine:

```
var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        Image("background_brown").resizable()
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            .frame(width:UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height:UIScreen.main.bounds.height)
            .border(Color.yellow, width: borderWidth)
        
        ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: true, content: {
            
            Text("hello")
        }).frame(width:UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height:UIScreen.main.bounds.height)
        .border(Color.yellow, width: borderWidth)
    }
}
```